# How do I get past human verification for a GET request to a Stack Overflow query?

Tags: support, captcha, api

I have a bot that runs a provided Stack Overflow query such as, https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=batch, and up until yesterday I had no problem running a query and checking the question count to see if a new question has been asked.

Now when I perform the [GET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) request it is redirecting me to a human verification link, which the bot is not a human so it can not get past.

Is there a way I can register my bot or provide it my user ID credentials? Or any other way I can allow my bot to do a simple get request on a query?

I do not understand why they would just now start preventing GET requests from bots. The API they have does not provide all the same functionality that I want for making a single query search.

The query that I currently try to use is:
https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=batch%2bwebsphere%20%5bjsr352%5d%20or%20%5bbatch-processing%5d%20or%20%5bjava-batch%5d%20or%20%5bwebsphere%5d%20or%20%5bwebsphere-liberty%5d%20is%3aquestion

Which cannot be produced through the API as an example.

Comment: Why can't you use the [API](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search)?

Comment: https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search/advanced?pagesize=35&order=desc&sort=activity&q=batch%2Bwebsphere%20%5Bjsr352%5D%20or%20%5Bbatch-processing%5D%20or%20%5Bjava-batch%5D%20or%20%5Bwebsphere%5D%20or%20%5Bwebsphere-liberty%5D%20is%3Aquestion&site=stackoverflow?

Comment: The API will not let me perform the same query that I can build using a URL.  The example at the bottom of my question is one example of this problem

Comment: Why not? It does work, see the link above, yielding the same 33 results. Anyway the answer is going to be: don't use the web front-end for bots, use the API. That the web front-end up till now didn't present you a CAPTCHA doesn't mean it was meant to be used like that.

Comment: You could simply build a bot that is intelligent enough to pass the captcha tests :-)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The following principles are at play:

- The web front-end (i.e. http://stackoverflow.com) is not meant for automated consumption (e.g. scrapers, bots).
- The API (i.e. http://api.stackexchange.com) is meant for automated consumption.

Apparently up till a short while ago, the former was not really enforced. Now it is, and your bot has to solve a CAPTCHA. That should be a strong indication you're doing something you shouldn't be doing.

When I [pass your query as `q` parameter to the API and apply the proper page size](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search/advanced?pagesize=35&order=desc&sort=activity&q=batch%2Bwebsphere%20%5Bjsr352%5D%20or%20%5Bbatch-processing%5D%20or%20%5Bjava-batch%5D%20or%20%5Bwebsphere%5D%20or%20%5Bwebsphere-liberty%5D%20is%3Aquestion&site=stackoverflow), I get exactly the same results as your [web link](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=batch%2bwebsphere%20%5bjsr352%5d%20or%20%5bbatch-processing%5d%20or%20%5bjava-batch%5d%20or%20%5bwebsphere%5d%20or%20%5bwebsphere-liberty%5d%20is%3aquestion), albeit in a different order.

Perhaps you've just not used the API correctly, but there's nothing really special about your query, and the API seems to fully support it.

So, to answer your title: you should not try to circumvent the limitations, you should try to fix your bot so it properly uses the API.